# YUI Compressor on Windows 7 - unable to minify multiple files

Tags: yui, bundling-and-minification, yui-compressor

I can minify individual files with the command

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar <file to compress> -o <output file>
```

But I cannot minify multiple files. I tried:

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar -o <output file> *.js
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar *.js -o <output file>
```

and

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type js -o <output file>
```

...no dice. Any suggestions?